# PROFTPD - Why permissions denied?

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd

I have installed proftpd on my server, I tried to connect to the server but I get LOGIN INCORRECT. I have seen the log and I found this:

> Apr 26 13:02:39 vmi**** proftpd[16738] vmi*****.*********.com (*********[::ffff:**.**.**.***]): notice: unable to use '~/' [resolved to '/home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite.com/web/']: Permission denied

The permission of /home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite/web are:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 mywebsite.com mywebsite.com 4096 2011-04-26 12:04 web
```

PROFTPD runs with proftpd:proftpd permissions.

TO solve this I have added proftpd user to mywebsite.com group.

Take a look at /etc/group

```
mywebsite.com:x:1003:proftpd
```

So I have added proftpd to the group and set RW permissions to /web directory.

I don't understand why I get PERMISSION DENIED.

Comment: What user name are you logging into proftpd with?

Comment: @phsr I'm tring to login with mywebsite.com user

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/275541/proftpd-why-permission-denied

Answer (score 4):

Every directory in the full path has to have `x` (execute) permission for the mywebsite.com user, otherwise he'll not be able to cwd into it. So you have to check permissions of:

```
/home 
/home/lighttpd
/home/lighttpd/vhosts
/home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite
/home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite/web
```

not only `/home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite/web`

Additionally `/home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite/web` should have `r` permission set to allow read the directory, i.e. list its content.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding `chmod o+r web` fix the issue.